# How to improve your knowledge in php development

Tags: php, standards

I wanted to ask for tips from experienced php developers, Please what are the tips and any general advice that you would give for someone who is trying to imporve her php knowledge?
I am currently a junior level developer, but I need to get to the mid-level/intermediate level of knowledge within the next two months.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

**I want things in along the lines of:**

Improving your logical thought flow process,

Improving your php programming knowledge,

Improving your communication skills,

Minimizing the need for micromanagement.


I just want to get to the point where I feel confident enough to **carry out a task within a logical time frame** and deliver in an **oo standards compliant way**. Also, to get to the point where I can be **trusted to lead small to mid-level projects**.
Thanks so much and I look forward to hearing from you

Comment: While interesting, I think this question is off topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Thanks Damien, could you let me know a better place I could get the answers I need? I dont mean to be off-topic, but since this is a development forum, thought its an okay question to ask

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to get to the point where I feel confident enough to carry out a task within a logical time frame and deliver in an oo standards compliant way.

This one is simple to answer: **use a framework.** Too bad, there are plenty of them for PHP. CodeIgniter, ZF, Symphony and Yii are major of them. My friends tend to use the latter one but in general terms they're all equal.

> to get to the point where I can be trusted to lead small to mid-level projects.

To lead projects is somewhat different and require more organizing skills rather than programming ones.

Comment: Thanks, we have a custom framework we use in the company already. So have that part down, any other hints or tips that you think set a mid-leveller apart from a junior/rank amateur?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to give yourself projects to do on your own for example create shopping carts or booking systems, read discussion forums try new techniques. And yes frameworks is also a good way to improve and with your current work you have done try make improvements on that where you were not using classes use classes. Lynda.com tutorials are also a good way to set your foundations.